# Chrome: can't access Trac projects

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, trac

I can easily access my [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) environments with Firefox, but when I do it with Chrome it asks me to authenticate, but doesn't let me in. Only the authentication dialog appears again and again. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something as simple as mistyped password?

I just tried to login to my Trac environment in Chrome. It will display authentication dialog each time you type in the wrong password (or user name). When user name/password is OK, you're logged in without problems.